# How do I enter the pipe symbol on my keyboard

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, pipe

On my keyboard there is a ¦ symbol: it's shown as the third character on a key with its position being on the bottom right of the key: I've been able to type it here by copying it to the clipboard from another web page.

But no combination of keys that I can think of allows the entry of the ¦ symbol from my keyboard. There are Ctrl, Fn, Win, Alt & AltGr keys on my keyboard. I'm not able to upload a photo of my keyboard as there's a 2mb limit on uploading images on this website.

There is no | symbol on my keyboard: also obtained from another web page.

*PS Hannu answered my question. But I am not able to mark his/her answer as 'Accepted' due to this website not giving me the option. Perhaps, this is because I am a new user.*

Comment: The various characters are in fact dependent on the layout (software) not the real keyboard, and the two may coincide or not. Please tell what keyboard layout you use in settings (language and subtype).

Answer (score 2):

Normally it is AltGr and the key with the symbol, e.g. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>|</kbd>
or possibly <kbd>AltGr</kbd> together with `¦`, i.e. a `|`-sign that has a "missing" portion in the middle of the vertical line.

For any character, you may also use the enter unicode / code point feature:

Hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> hit <kbd>u</kbd>, let go of all keys,
then type a hex code - and finally, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd>

The hex character code for the pipe symbol is `7c`, or the equivalent `007c`.
*(Note that the code point for the `¦`-character is `a6` and that this one will not work in common linux shell commands and scripts, if you attempt to use it in that context)*.

Find other code points with `Characters` or `Character map` - click on a character in there,
*('the same' as `Charmap` in Windows)*.

Ref:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en

Comment: Thanks for idea but this is a cumbersome method. Since the ¦ symbol is on the keyboard, there must be a way to type it more directly.

Comment: There is a "show physical keyboard" tool  somewhere, right now I cannot locate it though. This should allow you to find the key combo. Normally it is AltGr and the key with the symbol though.

Comment: Thanks, Hannu. That worked. Interestingly, it gave the | symbol rather than the ¦ symbol. But AFAIK they work exactly the same. PS I already use the Caps Lock key as a Compose key, as I often type French messages.

Comment: @Hannu - sorry, I’ve just seen that your comment is what I put as my answer - if you want to edit your answer to put in the AltGr - ¦ method, I’ll delete my answer & upvote yours.

Comment: Well, ;-) it should have been there already from the beginning, there now.